# Python: Writing multiprocess shared list in background

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I believe I am about to ask a definite newbie question, but here goes:

I written a python script that does snmp queries. The snmp query function uses a global list as its output.

```
def get_snmp(community_string, mac_ip):
    global output_list

    snmp get here

    output_list.append(output_string)
```

The get_snmp querier's are launched using the following code:

```
pool.starmap_async(get_snmp, zip(itertools.repeat(COMMUNITY_STRING),    input_list))
pool.close()
pool.join()

if output_file_name != None:
        csv_writer(output_list, output_file_name)
```

This setup works fine, all of the get_snmp process write their output out to a shared list output_list, and then the csv_write function is called and that list is dumped to disk.

The main issue with this program is on a large run the memory usage can become quite high as the list is being built.  I would like to write the results to the text file in the background to keep memory usage down, and I'm not sure how to do it.  I went with the global list to eliminate file locking issues.

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? If so, please accept it :).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your main problem with increasing memory usage is that you don't remove contents from that list when writing them to file. 
Maybe you should do `del output_list[:]` after writing it to file.

Answer (score 0):

Have each of the workers write their output to a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), then have another worker (or the main thread) read from the Queue and write to a file. That way you don't have to store everything in memory.

**Don't write directly to the file from the workers**; otherwise you can have issues with multiple processes trying to write to the same file at the same time, which will just give you a headache until you fix it anyway.